# Matching values in different columns, and place match in separate column, VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

This is what the current data looks like. Column **sku** has ~2K rows. Column **image** has ~8k rows. I removed file extension and leading zeroes from the image file names, so I can match easier.

[image]

Most of the images are not needed, only the first match is what I need. So you see in the example above, there is a match between column **sku/image** -- function would past value in middle column.

The desired outcome would look like below, note that **05099.jpg** & **05103.jpg** exist further down in **image** column:

[image]

I had help from another person on SO, they provided this function, however the dictionary is not filling the values in middle column. And I'm totally confused as to why, is it did work at first.

```
Function getSKUFromFilename(filename As String) As Long
    getSKUFromFilename = Val(filename)
End Function

Sub FillImageNames()
Dim ws As Worksheet, imageArr()
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

imageArr = ws.Range("C2:C" & ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row)

' (1) Fill Dictionary
Dim d As New Dictionary
Dim row As Long
For row = 1 To UBound(imageArr, 1)
    Dim filename As String, sku As Long
    filename = Trim(imageArr(row, 1))
    If filename <> "" Then
        sku = getSKUFromFilename(filename)
        d(sku) = filename
    End If
Next

' (2) Fill sheet
Dim lastRow as Long
lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
For row = 2 To lastRow
    sku = Val(ws.Cells(row, 1))
    If d.Exists(sku) Then
        ws.Cells(row + 1, 2) = d(sku)
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: This is easily achievable with formula, is vba necessary?

Comment: I'm not sure actually, can you give me a hint of which formula? I'm used to coding in PHP, not Excel, it's dreadful quite frankly.

Comment: `=INDEX(D:D,MATCH(A2,C:C,0)` and copy down the column in B.

Comment: Why are you using the last row of column `A` also for column `C`? Use `... ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "C") ...` instead.

Comment: @ScottCraner: Wow, that worked flawlessly and no need for VBA. Very impressive, thank you my friend!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Matching Transformed Data

[image]

**Excel Formula**

```
=IFNA(INDEX(C2:C8,MATCH(A2:A6,
    VALUE(LEFT(C2:C8,FIND(".",C2:C8)-1)),0)),"Nope")
```

```
=LET(sr,C2:C8,dl,A2:A6,e,"Nope",
   sl,VALUE(LEFT(sr,FIND(".",sr)-1)),
IFNA(INDEX(sr,MATCH(dl,sl,0)),e))
```

**VBA**

```vb
Function GetSkuFromImageName(ByVal Imagename As String) As Long
    GetSkuFromImageName = Val(Imagename)
End Function

Sub MatchImageNames()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    Dim srrg As Range: ' Source Return Range
    Set srrg = ws.Range("C2", ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp))
    Dim sData(): sData = srrg.Value ' assuming more than one cell
    
    Dim sDict As Object: Set sDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    Dim r As Long, sNumber As Long, sString As String
    
    For r = 1 To UBound(sData, 1)
        sString = CStr(sData(r, 1))
        sNumber = GetSkuFromImageName(sString)
        If sNumber > 0 Then
            If Not sDict.Exists(sNumber) Then ' ensuring first match
                sDict(sNumber) = sString
            End If
        End If
    Next r
            
    ' The keys of the dictionary hold the lookup data (numbers)
    ' while the corresponding items hold the return data (strings):
    Erase sData
            
    Dim dlrg As Range: ' Destination Lookup Range
    Set dlrg = ws.Range("A2", ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
    Dim dData(): dData = dlrg.Value ' assuming more than one cell
    
    Dim dValue, IsFound As Boolean
    
    For r = 1 To UBound(dData, 1)
        dValue = dData(r, 1)
        If VarType(dValue) = vbDouble Then ' is a number
            If sDict.Exists(dValue) Then
                IsFound = True
            End If
        End If
        ' Using the same array for the results.
        If IsFound Then
            dData(r, 1) = sDict(dValue)
            IsFound = False
        Else
            dData(r, 1) = "Nope" ' or Empty, or...
        End If
    Next r
    
    Dim drrg As Range: ' Destination Return Range
    Set drrg = dlrg.EntireRow.Columns("B")
    
    drrg.Value = dData
    
    MsgBox "Image names matched.", vbInformation
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Hmm, is this much code in VBA version really needed? Comment on OP accomplishes same thing with one line function. But thank you both work well!

Comment: You are the OP (*original poster*) so I don't know what you mean. You can easily copy the code to your module. I'm afraid efficient (fast) code most often requires more lines than basic (slow) code. Also, flexibility and readability require the same.

Comment: Ok, understood, your version is more performant. I thought OP stood for "Original Post"

Comment: `OP` --> means `Original Post` when referring to the post and `OP` also means `Original Poster` when referring to the poster. Off-Topic.

Answer (score 2):

Essentially, you want to compare a bunch of value pairs, and if those value pairs are equal, then write some information to a sheet.

You mentioned that you're working with a lot of data, so I recommend storing your data in an array, doing all of the work to find matches, and then writing everything back to the sheet.  This is much faster than comparing row-by-row in Excel.

Here's a simple example doing this:

[image]

```
Private Sub FillMatches()

    ' Store data in an array
    Dim RangeData As Range
    Set RangeData = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:D4")
    
    Dim ArrayImageInfo()
    ArrayImageInfo() = RangeData.Value
    
    ' Iterate through data and check for matches
    Dim ii As Long
    For ii = 1 To UBound(ArrayImageInfo, 1)
    
        If ArrayImageInfo(ii, 1) = ArrayImageInfo(ii, 3) Then
            ArrayImageInfo(ii, 2) = ArrayImageInfo(ii, 4)
        End If
    
    Next ii

    ' Write the data back to the sheet
    RangeData.Value = ArrayImageInfo
    
End Sub
```

And the result:

[image]